# C# Calling a function with multiple values

Tags: c#, function, call

So I have this code here :

```
int n;
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write("Please insert a number : ");
        n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Please insert wait time (0,1 or 2) : ");
        int time = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine())*1000;            
        Calculate(n,time);                      
    }
```

What is the best method for me to call the Calculate(n,time) function for multiple n values (given one after the other), but the same time. I already thought of using an array to store multiple n values, but is there a better option.

Also I would like to pass multiple n's as as arguments from the command line.

Any ideas? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you need just several values of n then tuple may be better than array.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just use params attribute.

```
public void Calculate(time, params int[] parameters){ ... }
```

This would allow you to call:

```
Calculate(time, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, ....)
```

In function you can iterate:

```
foreach(int item in parameters){}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// 
private void Calculate(int int_value, param int[] int_array_value)
{
`   enter code here`// your code goes here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An array should work perfectly.

```
public void Calculate(int[] numbers, int time)
{ ... }
```

Also with LINQ you can perform a distinct selection of your array:

```
Calculate(n.Distinct().ToArray(), time);
```